# typing for handler that either call a callback or return a promise

Tags: typescript, handler, union-types

I'm trying to fix the [Handler](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/handler.d.ts#L84) type in @DefinitelyTyped/aws-lambda. Handler functions can indicate their results in 2 ways: by either calling an input `callback` function, or by returning a `Promise`. It seems to me that the most correct way to model this is with a union of function types:

```
export type Handler<TEvent, TResult> = ((
    event: TEvent,
    context: Context,
    callback: Callback<TResult>,
) => void) | ((
    event: TEvent,
    context: Context,
) => Promise<TResult>);
```

However, functions that implement the `Promise`-branch of the union are not typed correctly:

```
const handler: Handler<string, string> = (event, context) => {
  return Promise.resolve('wow');
}
```

The errors given are that `event` and `context` have implicit `any` type, which should not be true at all. The return type is also not checked, making me suspicious that it is determined to be `void`.

Functions implementing the `callback`-branch are correctly typed:

```
const handler: Handler<string, string> = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'Hello World');
}
```

[Fuller example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFcFtoTwFABc4AcCmoDCB7AdkugB5KgC8oAzkgE4CWeA5gNwLGo42kobYCGAGwEAjPgGMA1gB4AKgCV0lSANIU+eOAD5yoABToaNTgH4AXKACihzqAA+VWg0Z3QeZQIA0oGouVIzoPK+KgCU5NoAbjh04KxsRBxcoDyYABLq4AIGshYR6AReQUoq2hS6ugigVaDoeQTmMrn5SB6V1WL4hCTmuATELW1VYoIi4hI9I6KSsgrFSJqtYWSR0eBh9uWDNXVIDU0FWx193did-YvhoAAKRtB0lOgzwfMhcQhH1KAAFhlZNObpPCZbLUehMLygpylPS1ZpeI5dFqgYZCKYSJbaADeh0mY10biEXgA5Kl0EIcKAAOqcATgImvBAAXwQ73wnx+QL+lKMTABvxBjnBDjBjGh+h28LOJHhuMkGNA2IAkCBkZwfGIkAI4KBhD4+BJKDjUXiCZ5QABmBnMhAq3XofWUcywgigDKq46kH55UB0aCoAR0MR0FCgInqOBE5JodCsvDs-k0ABMfM5ApFEMFop04rh7sR8uxVR8SEgNDw11u93QADofJQcAI8roiQB3HAt+msa22vUG0AAMxsSC+mBbPOcevreCdO1dQLz-W+fG9vv9geD2rDGkjKVj8dTSe5+EYKeBNCkkKFl6zZWdSIR-QLCGVYDwFIMRhooGgikofEY6DMN+fBwMImDFqW5YpKALZ8JQEDoIQNB3Hg6DgMkFJgaAUQxMYWwQWWFY4HcDy1ooDZNpaXYskAA)

How can I correctly create a type which is a union of two function types?